# Swing: saving and loading components

Tags: java, swing, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to save and load the state of a `JPanel` which has nested custom panels (instances of other classes) and various listeners.
These components have been created by Matisse, so they have private sub-components.

I've tried `XMLEncoder`/`XMLDecoder`, but it threw various exceptions on the serialization try.

With `XStream`, I can save and load the GUI state; however, it doesn't reload the listeners, leaving me stuck with a read-only component, which is undesirable.

So, this opens a little bunch of questions for me:

- Is there something I might be doing wrong with the `XStream` serialization?
- Is the access modifier of the sub-components relevant for any of those two libraries?
- Are there any other options for Swing component serialization worth exploring?
- Should I stick to serializing just the component logic?

Comment: Component serialisation is very, very difficult. Instead, you should be focusing storing the state of the values used by the UI instead. So instead of trying to store the physical state of the UI components, store the data that backs it. Ts way, you continue to initialise the UI components the same way each time, but then reapply the data based on what you've loaded. Jaxb might be worth exploring

Comment: *"..which has nested custom JPanels"*  Why 'custom'? *"..and various listeners. These components have been created by Matisse.."*  Oh right... the **IDE** is writing the code.  That doesn't bode well..  As stated by @MadProgrammer, it is the models backing / data in the components that it makes sense to serialize.